# SharePoint Workflow manager with three servers in workflow farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager

we installed workflow manager in our three SP 2013 servers and it is working fine.
Out of three servers say server1, server2, server3, server1 is consuming high RAM usage with the workflow backed manager service is using high RAM usage compared to other three servers.

Also, this server1 is processing less number of workflows compared to server2 and server3.

Please let us know how to troubleshoot for finding this high ram usage in only specific server.